# How to create a submatrix extracting each raw from a matrix that satisfy a logical condition?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, dataset

I have a  single *.txt file with multiple records, from an MPU6050 connected to Arduino.

I can recognize when a new record was made because the column time restart from a random value lower then the previous (is never 0).

The file is a nX7 which contains in order **time, ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz**

I am trying to extract the m subrecords from the single matrix, so i defined a logical if.

1. If time i > time i+1 keep track of the position from the original matrix and store in a submatrix (rangematrix) this boundary values.
2. From the rangematrix create a set of submatrices (the total number of submatrices will be [size(rangematrix,1)-1] .

I have a civil engineer background and i am a noob with Matlab.
Thanks for your time, thanks for you patience.

I tried to solve this with the code below, but I think is only rubbish.

```
%Open the file 
filename= uigetfile ('.txt');
fileID = fopen (filename);
logmpu6050 =csvread(filename);
fclose (fileID); 
n=length(logmpu6050);
%Count every time i>i+1 where i is the i,1 element of my dataset
for i=1:n-1
%Save the data of the i raw every time happens i>i+1
if logmpu6050(i,1)>logmpu6050(i+1,1);
rangematrix(i,:)= logmpu6050(i,:);
end
end
% Create a new sets of matrices from boundary values
```

I also read a lot of questions on stack but i didn't find the solution:

[MATLAB: extract every nth element of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891427/matlab-extract-every-nth-element-of-vector)

[Extract large Matlab dataset subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818107/extract-large-matlab-dataset-subsets)

[MATLAB: Extract multiple parts of a matrix without using loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906077/matlab-extract-multiple-parts-of-a-matrix-without-using-loops)

[MATLAB: Extracting elements periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625560/matlab-extracting-elements-periodically)

[Extract data from MATLAB matrix without for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070197/extract-data-from-matlab-matrix-without-for-loop)

[How to extract a vector from a large matrix by index in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055995/how-to-extract-a-vector-from-a-large-matrix-by-index-in-matlab)

[How to extract a part of a matrix with condition in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781736/how-to-extract-a-part-of-a-matrix-with-condition-in-matlab#comment17278169_12781913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use diff.

```
filename= uigetfile ('.txt');
fileID = fopen (filename);
logmpu6050 =csvread(filename);
fclose (fileID); 
n=length(logmpu6050);
%Count every time i>i+1 where i is the i,1 element of my dataset
rangematrix = logmpu6050(diff(logmpu6050(:,1)) > 0,:);
```

Comment: Thanks i will try It :)

Comment: why you use the end, if there is no if else statements? 
If i use `rangematrix = logmpu6050(diff(logmpu6050(:,1)) < 0,:);` i can know when this occur and i have a 5X7 matrix with the boundary values. If i use `rangematrix = logmpu6050(diff(logmpu6050(:,1)) < 0,:);`  in my specific case i get a 26.214X7  the original matrix is 26220X7 so the solution don't consider (logically correct) the end value of the matrix